# не срабатывает required

Tags: html, jquery

После подключения скрипта обработки формы, перестает работать required

```
<form id="main" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" name="name" placeholder="Как вас зовут?" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="email" placeholder="Укажите Вашу почту:" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="15" cols="65" name="text" placeholder="Ваш вопрос:" required></textarea>
        </div><br><br>
       <button id="form_one" class="donwload">Задать вопрос</button>
    </form>

 $("#form_one").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "dist/post/form.php",
        data: $("#main").serialize(),
        success: function(result){console.log(result)},
        error: function(err){console.log(err);}
    }).done(function() {
        console.log("Спасибо");
    });
});
```

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: А с чего вы взяли что required должен работать с Ajax ? required работает когда форма "явно" отправляет данные. Вам надо через JS сделать валидацию инпутов, и если всё норм, тогда и отправлять данные через AJAX

Comment: понял, спасибо!